# Angular2/Typescript object and property binding to template

Tags: typescript, angular

***Note: I want to know correct way or something more*** 
_____________________________________________________________________
***ANGULAR1***
In **`angular1`**, we could do something like below.

```
$scope.user={};
$scope.user.name="micronyks";
$scope.user.age="27";
```

or directly like

```
$scope.user={name:"micronyks",age:"27"}
```

Binding to template looks like,

```
<div>My name is {{user.name}} & I'm {{user.age}} year(s) old. </div>
```

______________________________________________________________________
***ANGULAR2***
In **angular2** with **Typescript**,

**models.ts**

```
export class LoginModel()
{
  private name:string;
  private age:number;
}
```

**app.ts**

```
import {LoginModel} from '../models.ts';

user=new LoginModel()
constructor()
{
   this.user.name="micronyks"
   this.user.age="27"
}
```

**app.html**

`<div>My name is {{user.name}} & I'm {{user.age}} year(s) old. </div`>

Can we directly create an object with property(ies) with values?

I know `TypeScript` is mainly concerned with `type`.

But would like to know if something else is there and if someone know something into deep.

If you want to show something you can use this plunker: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rrty3kV6t3jT40z2FnQB?p=preview)

Comment: Not sure what you asking for? You want to create a `LoginModel` instance like `new LoginModel("micronyks", 27)`?

Comment: Nope I know for that we can go with `constructor` of `LoginModel class`. As in angular1 we can do the stuff as shown, Is it somehow possible (something similar) in angular2?

Comment: You can show different way(s) if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use also use literal objects in Angular2 like Angular1. Since Angular2 can be used with TypeScript, you can leverage its strong types. This way you can specify the types for properties and parameters. Checks aren't now possible and this allows to get type errors if uncorrect types are used.

```
import {LoginModel} from '../models.ts';

export class Test {
  user:LoginModel = new LoginModel()

  constructor() {
    this.user.name = 'micronyks';
    this.user.age = 27;

    this.someMethod(this.user);
  }

  someMethod(user:LoginModel) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Another point is related to dependency injection since Angular2 can rely on type to know which instance to inject... Otherwise you need to use `@Inject` .

There are also impacts within your IDE. Since you can have completion if you define types instead of no type or `any`.

In fact, it's even possible to mix things:

```
interface INumbersOnly {
  [key: string]: number;
}

var x: INumbersOnly = {
  num: 1, // works fine
  str: 'x' // will give a type error
};
```

So I would say that you're free to do what you want ;-)

See this question for more details:

- [typescript strong typing - specifying object value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31985027/typescript-strong-typing-specifying-object-value-types)

Comment: Very nice... Thanks for explanation.