# Why autocomplete stop working in an object with type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, webstorm

I have a list of routes in one object and want to import it in other file and have autocomplete for object properties.

*index.ts*

```
import allRoutes from './routes';

allRoutes.routeHome;
```

*routes.ts*

```
const allRoutes = {
  routeHome: '',
  routePortfolio: 'portfolio'
};

export default allRoutes;
```

All works fine. But if I add types to my allRoutes for some typecheking like this:

```
const allRoutes: {[key: string]:string} = {
  routeHome: '',
  routePortfolio: 'portfolio'
};
```

or like this:

```
interface IRoutes {
    [key: string]: string;
}

const allRoutes: IRoutes = {
    routeHome: '',
    routePortfolio: 'portfolio'
};
```

Everything breaks down

I try this in WebStorm or VSCode. If I add a type for object properties - autocomplete stops working.
Why does it happen? And how I can fix this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Once you initialize the constant with type `{ [key: string]: string }`, the original type is lost.  If you want to preserve the original type but check that it is assignable to `{ [key: string]: string }`, you can do this:

```
function asStrings<T extends { [key: string]: string }>(arg: T): T {
  return arg;
}

const allRoutes = asStrings({
  routeHome: '',
  routePortfolio: 'portfolio'
});
```

There is a [suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26045) for a solution that would not require calling a function.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for an advanced solution. Why are original types lost? Can you give a link on a doc about this? I never hear it before. And this solution is best practice? It looks not very simple. Should I start to use it in my daily work?

Comment: That is the purpose of an annotation: TypeScript uses the annotated type and not the original type.  I don't know that this is stated explicitly anywhere in the documentation, but I did dig up a related suggestion thread and add it to the answer.  If you want to validate that all the elements of `allRoutes` are strings _and_ have autocomplete for members, I believe this is the best solution available; your only other option would be to give up one of those two things.  It's up to you what you think is best practice.

Comment: Wow this is brilliant, it even works with JSON imports, it will autocomplete the keys.

Comment: brilliant contribution mate

Comment: It's a real shame that suggestion you linked to hasn't got much traction :(

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with an interface with optional properties? When using {[key: string]: MyType}, MyType appears to be enforced while populating the object properties (e.g. routeHome, routePortfolio, etc.), but the resulting object (allRoutes) becomes a union type that no longer recognizes optional properties if some entries are missing them as keys

Comment: The main problem with this approach is that the object will keep it's original type in the end, which is most of the times the desired behaviour for key types but not for values. @McFixit Here is a workaround: `function keepPropOriginalType<T extends { [key: string]: MyType }>(arg: T) {
    type propType = keyof typeof arg
    return arg as { [originalPropType in propType]: MyType }
}`. See answer below for more details

Answer (score 4):

If you want to type your object without autocomplete loss and keep advantage of readonly you can use `as const`

```
const object = {
  title: "Autocomplete",
} as const
```

Comment: `as const` is a very underrated feature :-)

Comment: This is my preferred solution! You can even
```
const object: Record<string, T> = {
    title: "Autocomplete"
} as const
```

Comment: @KasparPoland I got `Cannot find name 'T'.ts(2304)`

Comment: What if you want to retain the typing constraints on the keys and values of an object? For example if you want to have `string`s as keys and `number`s as values, then what you wrote simply removes that typing constraints.

Answer (score 3):

Logged as [WEB-34642](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34642), please follow it for updates

Comment: This is a Jetbrains internal issue tracker if anyone is wondering...

Answer (score 3):

##### Generic solution for arbitrary type T (eg. enforce `{ [key: string]: T }` )

If you don't know the type in advance it's a little trickier to get this working. You need a factory function to create yourself a 'helper' function to enforce the type.

This is the best I could come up with - I think anything beyond this will require language changes:

```
export const AssertRecordType = <T>() => <D extends Record<string, T>>(d: D) => d;

type Dog = {
   breed: string
};

// Note the double function call
const dogs = AssertRecordType<Dog>()(
{
    abbie: { breed: 'Black labrador' },
    kim: { breed: 'Jack russel mix' }
});

// typing dogs.k will suggest kim
```

If you need to do this a lot you can create an alias for each one (you may want to rename the function to indicate it's a factory function `CreateRecordTypeAsserter` ?):

```
export const AssertStringRecord = AssertRecordType<string>();
export const AssertDogRecord = AssertRecordType<Dog>();
```

You can then use these anywhere with just a single function call which is ugly:

```
const dogs = AssertDogRecord({ bryn: { breed: 'Collie' } });
// dogs.b will suggest bryn
```

BTW: Don't get hung up on the function call, even if it's called a lot it's literally just returning the value that was passed in.

If you're still unclear what's happening, the expanded form may be easier to read:

```
// create a helper function to assert the type of a Record
export const AssertRecordType = <T>() => 
{
    // returns helper function using the 'captured' T
    return <D extends Record<string, T>>(d: D) => 
    {
        // return the original value, the function is just used to 
        // enforce the type
        return d;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this solution?

```js
interface IRoute {
    name: string;
    destination: string;
}

class AllRoutes {
    public static readonly Home: IRoute = { name: "Home", destination: "" }; 
    public static readonly Portfolio: IRoute = { name: "Portfolio", destination: "portfolio" }; 
}
```

Comment: This goes against what most will be trying to achieve - ensuring that each member of `AllRoutes` conforms to the same interface. This approach requires developers to always remember to add an interface, and correctly remember which interface they're supposed to add. Adding the wrong type or no type will potentially result in bugs.

Answer (score 2):

```
type RouteType = 'routeHome' | 'routePortfolio';

export const allRoutes: Record<RouteType, string> = {
  routeHome: '',
  routePortfolio: 'portfolio'
};
```

This should give the autocomplete.

Comment: This definitely works, but there's a 'yuck' factor in having to duplicate all the route names. In a bigger application with say 50+ routes, that `RouteType` is going to get harder to maintain, and developers may remove a member from `allRoutes` and forget to remove the corresponding type from `RouteType`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what helped me to have autocompletion and prevent typescript from moaning

```
type TPage = {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    path: string;
};

function asRecord<T extends Record<string, TPage>>(arg: T): T & Record<string, TPage> {
    return arg;
}

const EXAMPLES_PAGES = asRecord({
    chart2D_basicCharts_BandSeriesChart: {
        id: "chart2D_basicCharts_BandSeriesChart",
        title: "BandSeriesChart",
        path: "/chart2D_basicCharts_BandSeriesChart"
    },
    chart2D_basicCharts_FanChart: {
        id: "chart2D_basicCharts_FanChart",
        title: "FanChart",
        path: "/chart2D_basicCharts_FanChart"
    }
})

const currentExampleKey = Object.keys(EXAMPLES_PAGES).find(key => EXAMPLES_PAGES[key].path === location.pathname);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Simplest way to keep prop types while setting value type

When setting `{[prop: string]: MyType}`, the problem is that you override the natural type for object keys:

```js
const obj = { a:'a', b:'b' }

obj. // will autocomplete with a|b proposition but the type of obj.a will be string

const typedObj: {[prop: string]: MyType} = obj

obj. // will NOT autocomplete because it has lose the a|b key type
     // althougth the type of obj.a will be correctly interpreted as MyType
```

The best would be to define only the `: MyType` part in `{[prop: string]: MyType}` but keep the natural key type.

**So here is the solution**:

```js
const obj = { a:'a', b:'b' }

const typedObj = obj as {[keys in keyof typeof obj]: MyType}

// Now we get the right type for keys and values!
typeof typedObj // { a: MyType, b: MyType }
```

---

### Example usage:

```js
type Route = { path: string, orientation?:'portrait' |'landscape' }

const routes = typeObjectValues({
   home: { path: 'home' },
   videoPlayer: { path: 'player', orientation: 'portrait' },
})

const typedRoutes = obj as {[keys in keyof typeof routes]: MyType}
```

Check [this TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gV2NAvFA3lMBDYALALigGdgAnASwDsBzAGijkoiuFwrioH4CByMJuWwVgvKAB9eAG2xUAJsQDG2SGIC%20AWABQ2xZ1JQyiZMShpQkAPIAjAFYRFwAGrYpCCMQAU6bVD944AFsIIkwcfCJeAOD1Ol8-ADcKOQg4AAUZEAgyUKxcQih%20TOzeBiYKFjZgDipIgTIhEVj4kghgatpiNOwaEIw8iMLiNo6aYlLGZlZ2TkiZeSUVCGatNQBKbW0LaHgkCAA5bGDTNABrCBA4ADMobevDYw9NrSuEKkca2-AIG3tHFzcHgAPAAVKAQAAeyAW-QA2ucQERSJRaABdIi7ZBQNQAPk8cDsDmARBBawwLS%20kCwRjAIO%20ZigCPudxuBL%20wApZDaCDIVEYhMcUGwpkwsPKNGorjSNLpVOo1LgtO%206Ngj2x2jUQA)

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IRoutes {
    [key: string]: string;
}

export const allRoutes = {
  routeHome: '',
  routePortfolio: 'portfolio'
};

// Make TS check allRoutes, but leave it untyped to make autocomplete work.
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
const test: IRoutes = allRoutes;
```

This looks horrible and also gives no autocomplete inside `allRoutes`. I would not recommend this approach.

Comment: This does not help nor does it contribute to the conversation proactively.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another suggestion using `keyof typeof` and type casting:

```
type Routes<T extends string> = Record<T, string>;

export default allRoutes as Routes<keyof typeof allRoutes>;
```