# In typescript, can a generic function return an extended generic type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I was trying to add type checking to an const object and also keep the auto completion.

The very first attempt is
`const foo:{[key:string]:string} = {bar:"foobar"}`

Which does check the type, but the resultant type would not support autocomplete.
[Screen cap from VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Eqr.png)

Then I came across the answer provided from this question:
[Why autocomplete stop working in an object with type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146544/why-autocomplete-stop-working-in-an-object-with-type-in-typescript)

Which uses a function that returns the original argument with original type. It works great but it is not quite generic.

```js
export function asCSS<T extends { [key: string]: CSSProperties }>(arg: T): T {
  return arg
}
```

What I then tried is to make it generic by using a function that returns the function.

```js
function generateTypeCheck<T>(){
  return function asPropType<R extends { [key: string]: T }>(arg: R): R {
    return arg
  }
}

const foo = generateTypeCheck<string>()({bar:"foobar"}
```

[Has type checking, auto complete, and is generic. But too clumsy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7hOp.png)

The problem is when I attempt to shorten it, the type will be gone.

```js
export function checkType<T>(input) {
  return (generateTypeCheck<T>()(input))
}
```

[Lost type checking and autocompletion when shorten](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PC45Y.png)

Is it possible to do something like the last piece of code, but keep the type and auto completion?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use two functions, just use two generic parameters:

```js
function asPropType<T, R extends { [key: string]: T }>(arg: R): R {
    return arg
}

const foo = asPropType({ bar:"foobar" });
foo.bar;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQwM4AUBOcAOAVATxwFMAePAGkQCVFiAPKYsAE1UQG9EBtAa2IIAuRKiiYYYAOYBdYXkQBfAHwAKZJknDqASi2cAUIiOJMxKCExJ1k-Qv36ICUYmBw4iALwoM2fEWIqXABG6oIARK5wIZhhitoA3PqRAHTRiUA)

Comment: This will allow all possible types of input object values, such as
```const foo = asPropType({ bar: 'foobar', foo: 123 })```
 My intention is to enforce type check on the object properties, such that the object properties can only be a specified type.